# Parallel Processing in Weblogic using WorkManager

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, jms, weblogic

I have three servers and scheduling one task using application WorkManager. At a time only one node processes this task. Now I want to schedule this task in parallel  i.e. run in 3 threads. Paralleling this task on one server/JVM is easy. But not able to find a way where I can schedule a task/work on remote JVM. For example, task is divided in 3 sub tasks and all 3 JVMs running this task in parallel.

I tried creating Global WorkManager and targeted other server(Server2). I ran main job on Server1 and scheduled work using Global Work Manager. But that did not work and work was scheduled on Server1 only.

There is RemoteWorkItem interface provided by commonj. But not sure Weblogic has provided implementation of this interface or not. I am using weblogic 10.3 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/javadocs/commonj/work/RemoteWorkItem.html

Is there a way out there using WorkManager or I have to go with the messaging solution only?

Answer (score 0):

Work Managers are used to constrain how many work requests a particular WLS instance will execute at once. They're designed more for server stability than for forcing distributed workloads, as evidenced by the fact that you can (and should) set work managers even on single node clusters.

I think you'll have to focus more on how the work items are distributed to each server in the cluster, since the solution is load balancing *within* the constraints of the work managers.